# Jquery form validation on input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I currently have a form which changes dynamically. I'm using all text inputs but they all should only accept numbers.

```
    $("#result-form").validate({
            rules: {
                .text: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                .text:{
                required: " Please enter a score!",
                digits: " Please only enter numbers!"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

Currently i try to validate using the above but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the code that creates the elements dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it like this...

```
$("#result-form").validate({
    rules: {
        .text: {  // <-- MUST only be a NAME attribute
            required: true,
            digits: true
        }
    },
    ....
```

When declaring your rules using `.validate()` method, you can only declare them using the `name` attribute.

---

If you're creating form elements dynamically, rules can only be changed or applied using [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).  You would call this immediately *after* creating the new element and they can be targeted using any jQuery selector you wish.

This code will dynamically apply these rules to all `type="text"` fields on the page.

```
$("#result-form").validate({  // initialize plugin
    // other rules and options
});

$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        messages: {
            required: " Please enter a score!",
            digits: " Please only enter numbers!"
        }
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2U68C/**

**NOTES**:

- You **must** wrap `.rules()` in a jQuery `.each` if/whenever the selector may contain more than one element.  If you fail to do this, only the first matched element will be validated.
- You **must** ensure that all form input elements being considered for validation contain *unique* `name` attributes.  It's how the plugin keeps track of the inputs.  If you fail to do this, only the first matched element will be validated.

---

**SIDENOTE**:

You don't need this at all...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
}
```

This is already the default behavior.  In fact, `form.submit()` is the same code inside the plugin.  In other words, you do not need to call the `submitHandler` in this case.   You'd only need to use it if/when you need to over-ride or augment, such as with `ajax()`.

Comment: i've tried this and works for the initial ones but any new ones created don't validate. Any ideas why? I'm currently using the code from the link you gave.

Comment: @adamcarlin, you have to call the `rules()` method after you create new elements.

Answer (score 1):

just to complement [@Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky)'s answer, if you add

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $(e.target).valid();
});
```

you can validate dynamically (in the first time, the input only will be validate after you click out, or focus to some other element)

Answer (score -1):

Use the `name` instead of the `class`.

```
rules: {
   nameoftextbox: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
    }
}
```

To use it with classes:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("classname", {
  required: true,
  digits: true
});
```

Comment: The id could change because I can add elements that need validating by pressing a button the page.

Comment: The first half of your answer is technically incorrect.  [You can only use the `name` attribute to declare rules inside of the `.validate()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/).  Not `id`, not `class`, nor anything else except the `name`.

Comment: Damn! I must have misread the documentation. Thanks for your correction! +1

Answer (score -1):

You can add the 'required digits' attributes in the input tags, and do:

```
var validator = $( "#result-form" ).validate();
validator.form();
```

This will also allow you to choose specifically which of the text boxes are required.
For further reading I suggest you read http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/