# JS: Form validation on input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to do some form validation, however don't want to to select form input by class name. Is there a way I can loop through the validation based on input attribute type. I've had a play with the code, but to little avail. Potentially thinking something along these lines:

EDIT: I don't want to use a plugin

```
function validator (myForm) {

  // If type equals Email
  if($(myForm + " input").attr("type") == "email") {
    // Validate Email Here
  }

  // If type equal text
  if($(myForm + " input").attr("type") == "text") {
    // Validate Text Here
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `myForm`? A string? A DOM element?

Comment: You might like to use HTML5 <input type="email" pattern ="RegEXP">..
u need to supply regexp only if u want something extra from default..

Comment: similar question asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174977/jquery-form-validation-on-input-type  Use Jquery validator

Comment: You appear to have a solution in your question. What problem do you have?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing javascript-only validation, unless you have backend validation too, as someone can simply bypass it by disabling javascript

Comment: I'm aware of that, this is just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like that.

First, if `myForm` is a DOM element, then you'll want `$(myForm).find(...)` rather than `$(myForm + " ...")`, because the latter will result in an invalid selector. If `myForm` is a string containing a valid selector, it's fine.

Your `if($(myForm + " input").attr("type") == "email") {` won't work because what that will do is get the `type` of the **first** `input` in your form and compare it to the string `"email"`. It won't find all the email inputs in your form.

You can select specific types of inputs using an attribute selector, e.g.:

```
$(myForm).find("input[type=email]").each(function() {
    // Validate email inputs; each input is available as `this`,
    // which is a DOM element
});
```

and

```
$(myForm).find("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    // Validate text inputs; each input is available as `this`,
    // which is a DOM element
});
```

(In this case, we don't need quotes around the attribute values because they're single words.)

You might also look into the [HTML5 form validation stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation).

And of course, you probably know this, but any validation you do with client-side JavaScript (or other browser features) is **purely for UI/UX purposes**. You still have to validate things on the server, as client-side validation can be completely bypassed...

Answer (score -1):

you can find input element by attribute like below.

```
//If type equals Email
$('input [type = email]')
// If type equals Email
$('input [type = text]')
```

like above you can access.